# Specify path of sqlite database

Tags: database, html, sqlite

I'm trying to create a standalone HTML5 document that utilizes SQlite.  I want to save the database in the same directory as the html file so that I can access the data on a usb stick from any computer.  How do I specify where the database ought to be saved?

This is all I have so far:

```
var db = window.openDatabase("gtd", "", "GTD 3.0", 1024*1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, the browser handles how and where the SQLite database is created or read from. Firefox places the SQLite db into a file inside the user's profile folder.

> In Firefox the DOM storage data is stored in the webappsstore.sqlite file in the profile folder (there's also chromeappsstore.sqlite file used to store browser's own data, notably for the start page - about:home, but potentially for other internal pages with "about:" URLs).

(from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage)